# Filtering results based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query result with 4 columns, The 3rd column is the date in epoch unix time. The query takes a date parameter for example '7/1/2017'

What I want to do is choose the records that are before the date entered, but there could be two sets that both have dates in the future. I want the closest date.

So in the example below the leaseCode 'EDM09GW'  with the date '1533013200000' would be the closer date to 7/1/2017

I do not want records EDM09GW | 1690779600000 in the resultset.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
LeaseCode|BaseAmount      |ExpDate        |PaymentType
---------|----------------|---------------|-----------------
COR01GW  |-2.249938000000 | 1519797600000 | HST / PST Contra
COR01GW  |-1.125092000000 | 1519797600000 | GST Contra
COR01GW  | 1.125092000000 | 1519797600000 | GST (5%)
COR01GW  | 2.249938000000 | 1519797600000 | HSTNL
COR01GW  | 25.875154000000| 1519797600000 | Base
EDM01CL  |-1.740542000000 | 1540962000000 | GST Contra
EDM01CL  | 1.740542000000 | 1540962000000 | GST (5%)
EDM01CL  | 3.885136000000 | 1540962000000 | Realty Tax
EDM01CL  | 13.238843000000| 1540962000000 | Op Costs
EDM01CL  | 19.425027000000| 1540962000000 | Base
EDM09GW  |-2.429500000000 | 1533013200000 | GST Contra
EDM09GW  | 2.429500000000 | 1533013200000 | GST (5%)
EDM09GW  | 8.169002000000 | 1533013200000 | Realty Tax
EDM09GW  | 9.250506000000 | 1533013200000 | Op Costs
EDM09GW  | 33.600000000000| 1533013200000 | Base
EDM09GW  |-2.429500000000 | 1690779600000 | GST Contra
EDM09GW  | 2.429500000000 | 1690779600000 | GST (5%)
EDM09GW  | 8.169002000000 | 1690779600000 | Realty Tax
EDM09GW  | 9.250506000000 | 1690779600000 | Op Costs
EDM09GW  | 33.600000000000| 1690779600000 | Base
```

My expected result is to only have the    `EDM09GW | 1533013200000` columns and **NOT** the `EDM09GW | 1690779600000` columns

Comment: add your expected output

Comment: I've added my expected results.